# User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. Google Analytics 4

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using version 2.14.0 of [this lib](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), Laravel 10 and PHP 8.2 for get Data Google Analytics (GA4) but I'm getting the error:
`{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "errors": [ { "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }`

I'm using service account authentication, I also added the service account email in the Google Analytics access properties, but I still get the permission error, here's the code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();

        try {
            $jsonKey = storage_path('auth.json');
            $client->setAuthConfig($jsonKey);
        }
        catch (Google_Exception $ex) {
            abort(500, $ex);
        }

        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

        $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
        $response  = $this->getReport($analytics);
        $result    = $this->getResults($response);

        dd($result);
}
```

```
public function getReport($analytics)
    {
        // I changed it to X just to not display my property ID, but in the code the ID is correct as in Analytics
        $VIEW_ID = 'ga:XXXXXX';

        $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
        $dateRange->setStartDate('today');
        $dateRange->setEndDate('today');

        $pageviews = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
        $pageviews->setExpression('ga:pageviews');
        $pageviews->setAlias('pageviews');
        $hour = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $hour->setName('ga:hour');

        $pages = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $pages->setName('ga:pagePath');

        $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
        $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
        $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
        $request->setMetrics(array($pageviews));
        $request->setDimensions(array($hour, $pages));

        $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
        $body->setReportRequests(array($request));

        return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

```
public function getResults($reports) : array
    {
        $date = [];

        foreach ($reports as $report)
        {
            $header = $report->getColumnHeader();

            $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
            $metricHeaders    = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();

            $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

            foreach ($rows as $key => $row)
            {
                $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
                $metrics    = $row->getMetrics();

                for($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++)
                {
                    if ($dimensionHeaders[$i] === 'ga:pagePath')
                    {
                        $date[$key]['pagina'] = str_replace('/atlas/2017_portal_atlas', '', $dimensions[$i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $date[$key]['hora'] = $dimensions[$i];
                    }
                }

                for ($j = 0; $j < count($metricHeaders) && $j < count($metrics); $j++)
                {
                    $metricHeaders[$j];
                    $values = $metrics[$j];

                    foreach ($values->getValues() as $key2 => $value)
                    {
                        $date[$key]['acessos'] = $values->getValues()[$key2];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $date;
}
```

I tried to look for access to the site on the days defined in the code, but I get a permission error.

Comment: It seems that you are still using the code related to Universal Analytics and not GoogleAnalytics4, since they are two different APIs you should use the correct code to read